# swing, build and make GUI, empty screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a swing program. First I create frame and then to that frame I insert JPanel, which contains all graphical components.
Somehow, I'm not able to draw bottom panel. I only have empty window.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new buildGUI());
            frame.pack();
            frame.getContentPane();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().validate();
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    }

    .
    .
    .


    public class buildGUI extends JPanel {
        public void buildGUI() {
            bottomPanel = new JPanel(); 
            bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            // build gui here, add components to bottomPanel
            frame.add(bottomPanel);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            // this works
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // here I want to draw my app gui
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the bottom panel have any components? If not you won't be able to see much of it...

Comment: It has million components.

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this feeling you're messing up classes with methods. Also a lot of useless code seems to have sneaked into your code.

The first point comes from the fact you don't start your class name with a capital. A better class name would be: `BuildGUI`, but even that is a little bit dubious for a panel. Next you're calling the constructor of the method with `frame.add(new buildGUI())`, but this won't call the `void buildGUI()` method.

The second point comes from the `frame.getContentPane()` which returns the content pane of the frame. Because the content pane isn't being stored, this code does nothing and can as well be omitted.

My solution (staying as close as possible to yours), would look as follows:

```
@Override
public void run() {
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.buildGUI();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}

...

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public void buildGUI() {
        bottomPanel = new JPanel(); 
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        // build gui here, add components to bottomPanel
        this.add(bottomPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s still containing lots of useless code. `pack()` implies validation and `setVisible(true)` on a frame implies that it will be painted when visible. So the calls to `validate()` and `repaint()` on the content pane are obsolete. Further, I recommend removing `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` as unless there is a strong (documented) reason to mess around with the window placement policy, just leaving everything at the defaults is the best option. So what’s left then is opening a frame filled with nested empty panels…

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that content of frame is not repainted automatically.

Comment: @Holger I must admit I'm not really at home in `java.swing` etc and I wasn't sure whether they wouldn't be useful for one or another reason, but thanks. I edited my answer. This way I learn again as well :)

Comment: @user3463614: if your GUI isn’t repainted after certain user interactions, you will have to post the relevant code processing these user-activities. Adding `repaint()` calls to the *initialization* code does not help in any way.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class buildGUI extends JPanel {
        public /*void*/ buildGUI() {
            bottomPanel = new JPanel(); 
            bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            // build gui here, add components to bottomPanel
            // frame.add(bottomPanel);
        }
```

Your buildGUI constructor shouldn't have  return type.

frame.add is also not necessary, since your adding it when instantiating.

probably you need to add the bottomPanel to "this";

```
this.add(bottomPanel)
```

to actually add the bottomPanel to the buildGUI panel (since your extending JPanel, buildGUI is also a JPanel) or refer to "this" instead of bottomPanel.

Comment: this.add(bottomPanel); helped. But GUI is not repaint after some user interaction with it.

Comment: Have you also looked into the other comment? if buildGUI() is supposed to be your constructor, you should remove the return type "void". In my oppinion it is bad practise to name a method same as your class when it's not your constructor. It's confusing.

Comment: I did. Do I need to call somehow that repaint function when I change something or it is done automatically? For example I click in menu on item

Comment: Normally the repaint() method is called automatically when needed, though it doesn't always does so as wanted. Feel free to try around.

Comment: Maybe instantiate buildGUI (please use normal Classname BuildGUI, but I'll stick to your example) like this: buildGUI b = new buildGUI(); and then call b.repaint.